# Is complement of clopen set always clopen?

Tags: general-topology

Consider an open set $A$. Assume that its complement comp($A$) is an open set. That makes $A$ a clopen set. However since the complement of  comp($A$) is $A$ itself, that means that comp($A$) is also clopen. Am I correct in my reasoning?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, exactly. An equivalent definition to a set being open (resp. closed) is that its complement is closed (resp. open), so you are right on.

Comment: But I read that an open set can have an open complement, which means that you cant define an open set by its complement being closed. Is that wrong?

Comment: @DenisDavydov an open set can have an open complement iff it is actually clopen. It *can* happen ($\emptyset$ is an example in any space).

Answer (score 1):

As a clopen set $C$ is open, $C^\complement$ is closed (as *its* complement is $C$ again and this is open).

As $C$ is closed, $C^\complement$ is open. Both follow by the *definition* of a closed set as the complement of an open set.

So $C$ clopen implies $C^\complement$ clopen too.